# turn the hotspot on automatically in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

i have make a simple lan multiplayer game in unity (just for learn).
this is the main code (for connection):

```
    using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class StartServer : MonoBehaviour {
    public Transform Makan;
    public Transform CubeOBJ;
    public string SSS; 


    void OnGUI () {
        GUILayout.Box (Network.player.ipAddress);

        if (Network.peerType == NetworkPeerType.Disconnected)
        {
            SSS = GUILayout.TextField (SSS);
            if (GUILayout.Button ("StartServer"))
            {
                Network.InitializeServer(10, 25000);
            }


            if (GUILayout.Button ("Connect"))
            {
                Network.Connect (SSS, 25000);
            }

        } 
        else 
        {
            if (GUILayout.Button ("creatCube")) 
            {
                Network.Instantiate (CubeOBJ, Makan.transform.position, Makan.transform.rotation, 0);
            }
        }


    }
}
```

it works good.
the problem is that in mobile devices i should make (turn on) hotspot by myself in one of the devices.
how can i do this automatically?

Comment: What operating system?

Comment: Android operating system.

Comment: @Droppy is there any way to active hotspot automatically in android??

Comment: I don't know.  However I don't even understand why you want to activate hotspot as I cannot see how that affects your game.

Comment: @Drpppy i just want to learn how can i turn on hot spot. and i figure it out. its simple: cant do it in unity :) the only way is to make plugin in java to do that (using android studio or..) for unity.